# How can i add security to my gravitee.io api with keycloak?

Tags: keycloak, gravitee

i try to add security to my Api defined in Gravitee.io  with a keycloaK apikey .

I've tried to add resource in my api conf but i not found resource "Keycloak provider" to paste my keycloak json file.  like in the last screenshot of this readme :

https://github.com/gravitee-io/breizhcamp-2018-tia

I use Gravitee.io 1.24 (last docker image)  and keycloak    5.0.0
please help me ;-)

Comment: On new Gravitiee version 3, there is a built in capability to configure keycloak: https://docs.gravitee.io/apim/3.x/apim_installguide_authentication_keycloak.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download the keycloak resource plugin and drag & drop the zip file into the both directories 'plugin' of your instances (gateway and management) :) You can found it at this link : https://download.gravitee.io/graviteeio-apim/plugins/resources/gravitee-resource-oauth2-provider-keycloak/

Have a good day :)